# Securing a Sails API

Tags: android, angularjs, sails.js

I made an API using Sails.js. I dont want to expose this API to the public, but I want to write two clients for it, one is going to be a web client (AngluarJs probably) and the other will run on Android phones.

I don't want to expose the API because each client has a set of controllers it can access, and each user has a number of privileges.

For this I thought about maybe 2 steps: 
1/ Identify that the request came genuinely from one of my apps
2/ Check if the user has the privilege to access that part of the API

Is there any module that does this?

Comment: The sails.js gitter room is also a good place to chat and get support: https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure different kinds of policies in sails. As an example for authentication,Authorization and for some other custom check also.

Check this [Sails Policies Config](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Policies)

There are also different kinds of sails extensions available like

1. [sails-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-auth): Passport-based Authentication Extension, including Basic
   Auth
2. [sails-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-permissions): Permissions and Entitlements system for sails.js:
   supports user authentication with passport.js, role-based
   permissioning, object ownership, and row-level security.

Comment: It's worth noting that `sails-permissions` users `sails-auth`.